# Can I use the Scala lift-json library to parse a JSON into a Map?

Tags: json, scala, lift

Is there a way to use the lift-json library's JObject class to act like a Map?

For example:

```
val json = """
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ca63596ae65a71dd376938e"} , "foo" : "bar" , "size" : 5}
"""

val record = JsonParser.parse(json)
record: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(_id,JObject(List(JField($oid,JString(4ca63596ae65a71dd376938e))))), JField(foo,JString(bar)), JField(size,JInt(5))))

</code>
```

I would have expected record("foo") to return "bar"

I noticed a values function and it prints out a Map but the actual object is a JValue.this.Values?

`scala> record.values
res43: record.Values = Map((_id,Map($oid -> 4ca63596ae65a71dd376938e)), (foo,bar), (size,5))`

scala> record.values("foo")
:12: error: record.values of type record.Values does not take parameters
       record.values("foo")

There are examples with the lift-json library extracting a case class but in this case, I don't know the json schema in advance.

Comment: This is a related answer for parsing Map as an parameter in a case classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051290/deserializing-case-classes-with-mapstring-any-properties-with-lift-json/6310493#6310493

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the implementation, you'll see

```
case class JObject(obj: List[JField]) extends JValue {
  type Values = Map[String, Any]
  def values = Map() ++ obj.map(_.values.asInstanceOf[(String, Any)]) // FIXME compiler fails if cast is removed
}
```

So this should work:

```
record.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("foo")
```

You could also try

```
record.values.apply("foo")
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one works, the second option of using apply() returns an error. I ended using scala's builtin java parser. scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(record) will return a Some(Map) or Some(List)

Answer (score 7):

JValue.Values is a path dependent type. Meaning that if you hold on a JString it will be a String, or if you got a JArray it will be a List[Any]. If you are sure that the JSON you parse is a JSON object you can cast it to a proper type.

```
val record = JsonParser.parse(json).asInstanceOf[JObject]
```

A path dependent type for JObject is a Map[String, Any], thus:

```
scala> record.values("foo")                                     
res0: Any = bar
```

Just of curiosity, isn't it a bit problematic if you do not know the shape of data you are going to parse?

Note, if your data contains (name, description, age) and the age is optional you can read that JSON into:

```
case class Person(name: String, description: String, age: Option[Int])
```

Comment: I have a json which has an array of different fields. For ex. the first document may have (name, description, age) but the second document may only have (name, age) specified. If i use scala's Map object, i can just call document.getOrElse("foo", "")