# Having problems parsing JSON object - JField(xyz,JDouble(90.21)) and accessing the value "xyz"

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I have parsed a response from an HTTP API using the parse() function from the Lift library

```
val resultObj = parse(response)
val dps = resultObj \\ "dps"
println("dps are "+dps)
```

I have something like this now :

```
JObject(List(JField(1410418778,JDouble(0.0)), JField(1410418947,JDouble(0.0)),       JField(1410419163,JDouble(0.0)), JField(1410419314,JDouble(0.0)))
```

I want to retreive "1410418778" and the corresponding double value i.e 0.0 out of this.

I have tried the following :

```
dps.children.foreach(element=>{
  println("element "+element+ "and its extract is Double "+
    element.extract[Double]+" and its String extract is "+
    element.extract[String])
  val child = element.children
  println("element child "+child)
})
```

output ::

```
element JField(1410420437,JDouble(1.0))and its extract is Double 1.0 and its String extract is 1.0
element child List(JDouble(1.0))
```

Hoever both extract[String] and extract[Double] are giving only the value in the JDouble() field. Hw do i extract the string timestamp out of this too?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was unnecessarily complicating the answer. It is as direct as this :

```
val resultMap : Map[String , Any] = dps.asInstanceOf[JObject].values
    println(resultMap)
```

Got from here :

[Extract Json values as Map with lift-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571259/extract-json-values-as-map-with-lift-json)