# Get case class and JSON object from a hierarchical JSON map with lift-json

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I get maps such as:
`Map(reference -> Map(scriptRenderings -> List(Map(text -> महा-सुभाषित-सङ्ग्रहे 9979, scheme -> null, startLetter -> म)), jsonClass -> QuoteText, metre -> None, key -> महा-सुभाषित-सङ्ग्रहे9979, language -> Map(code -> UNK))`)
from my couchdb-lite database library.

- I need to convert them into case classes [I've defined](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/sanskritnlpjava/blob/9a7ca1c73099689c79f976bd1a907daf1d4ef756/src/main/scala/sanskritnlp/quote/Quote.scala#L74). How do I accomplish this (preferably with lift-json, which I'm already using)?
- And how to convert this map to a JSON object ? (Essentially reversing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571259/extract-json-values-as-map-with-lift-json).)

Comment: Stumbled upon a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181845/how-can-i-transform-a-map-to-a-case-class-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up converting the map to string and parsing the string to the case class:

```
    val jsonStr = Serialization.writePretty(jsonMap)
//    log debug jsonStr
    val quoteText = Serialization.read[QuoteText](jsonStr)
```